# Having Trouble with Exchange Archive Errors - 365 Hybrid

Tags: powershell, exchange, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline, exchange-hybrid

I work in a hybrid 365 environment. Someone made some changes to the archives for users' mailboxes and now I'm getting errors in 365 admin center when I look at an active user:[image of error box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7dUt.png)

I was able to get the details on the errors in AAD Connect powershell with the following:
**(Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName user@domain.com).errors[0].ErrorDetail.objecterrors.errorrecord.ErrorDescription**

It returned this for most users: **Failed to enable the new cloud archive  of mailbox  because a different archiveexists. To enable the new archive, first disable the archive on-premises. After the next Dirsync sync cycle, enable the archive on-premises again.**

One big issue, is that when I do this, it seems to completely remove the archive from the user, and create a completely new one, which is not what I want. Is there a way to keep the archive in place without making a new one? Even if I set the GUID of the existing archive, it just makes a new empty one. I can backup the archive to a .pst beforehand, but there's gotta be a better way, right?

After I performed the recommended fix on a couple users that didn't matter, I their archive mailbox, albeit empty, look correct in all places. However, when I select a user in 365 admin center, I still get the gray error boxes pictured above. Now when I enter the commands to view the error details, they're blank: [image of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LYBB.png)

If anyone has dealt with this before and can offer some guidance, it would be greatly appreciated. I'm a bit stumped here and I've almost exhausted all my resources. Please let me know if there's any other info I can provide that would help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is what I tell everyone when they have an Office 365 issue that they can't figure out: Open a support case with Office 365. It's free. You'll learn some new Office 365 chops and you'll get your issue resolved.

Comment: I opened a support case with MS yesterday and we're starting to get somewhere with this.  You're absolutely correct, I am learning more about my 365 setup in the process!

Answer (score 0):

Check the GUID of same mailbox from on-premise Exchange and O365:

```
Get-Mailbox "user identity with error status" | ft Name, ArchiveGuid
Get-RemoteMailbox -Identity "user identity with error status" | fl DisplayName, ArchiveGuid
```

Then update the remote mailbox properties with the ArchiveGuid value obtained from Azure AD:

```
Set-RemoteMailbox -Identity  “user identity with error status” -ArchiveGuid *
```

Then start a directory synchronization and see if the issue resolves.